# How do I programmatically determine which Mac drive is the boot drive?

Tags: macos, cocoa, boot, iokit

Great information on interrogating mounted drives via IOKit in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2019244/79202). But is there a way to determine which of the devices returned by `IOIteratorNext()` is the boot drive? Or better yet, might there be a way to get just the boot drive in the iterator returned by `IOServiceGetMatchingServices()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Booting is done from media, not a device per se. Devices have media, media have volumes. I don't believe that volumes are represented in IOKit.

This is probably easiest using Disk Arbitration. Use `DADiskCreateFromVolumePath()` with the `CFURL` for `/`. Then call `DADiskCopyDescription()` to get the description dictionary. That will include properties of the volume, the media, the device, and even the bus, including IOKit paths if you need them. There's a good chance the information you're looking for is directly in the description dictionary, though.

The NVRAM information cited by Mark Setchell is available from IOKit, too, at path `IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/AppleEFIRuntime/AppleEFINVRAM`. There's a property `efi-boot-device`. Its value is a property list including a service matching dictionary. As you can see, it looks for an entry with provider class of `IOMedia` whose `UUID` property is a certain UUID.

Comment: Thank you, this answer, along with the code example in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17039361), was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
nvram efi-boot-device

efi-boot-device <array><dict><key>IOMatch</key><dict><key>IOProviderClass</key><string>IOMedia</string><key>IOPropertyMatch</key><dict><key>UUID</key><string>78025031-4C42-4FDE-8DD1-A515A2BF6032</string></dict></dict><key>BLLastBSDName</key><string>disk0s3</string></dict></array>%00
```

Comment: This is calling a command line tool to do the dirty work. He wants it programmatically.

Comment: You don't always get what you want, and sometimes you have to settle for something close that does the job - maybe until you find something better. There"s no law against writing programs to use command-line tools, you know - that's what `system()` was written for. And there's nothing to install, Apple supply `nvram` on all Macs so it's not an external package dependency.

Comment: What @SevenBits said. I can `stat("/")`, but if there is some way to look it up in the registry without having to call `system()` or `stat` the file system, it would be much safer, because I doubt that the alternative would work well in a sandbox.

Comment: Maybe you can use this as a clue... http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-550.10/nvram.tproj/nvram.c

Comment: @theory If it won't work programmatically in your app, then it won't work by calling another program. A process created by a sandboxed process inherits the sandbox. This is a security feature; otherwise, the sandbox would be so easily circumvent able it would be useless.

Comment: I would take a look at @Ken Thomases' answer above; it might work.